# How to reduce the load time of items inside the Dropdown

Tags: java, ajax, html, for-loop

I am trying to load the 100 000 items into the dropdown list on the click event of the button. but it too slow to load. how to reduce the loading time of items?

Loop for Product

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        out.print("<option>Product" + i + "</option>");
    }
```

Ajax

```
    <script>
        function getproduct() {
            var output;
            var xhtp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhtp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhtp.readyState === 4 && xhtp.status === 200)
                    output = output +xhtp.responseText;
                   }
                }
                document.getElementById("product").innerHTML = output;
            }
            xhtp.open("post", "ProductController", true);
            xhtp.send();
        }
 </script>
```

Comment: You should consider using a Database, or take a look at reactjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A drop down menu containing 100,000 elements is not a good user experience. I recommend you provide a [typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) functionality instead.

Instead of fetching all the content in one go, build a search API, which would filter the results. Your UI should give the user an option to search (partial match or exact match as you prefer) and on search, show relevant search results for the user to choose from, as a drop down.

The only way you can optimize this 'load everything' scenario is if you can do incremental loading. Your data supplier API/method should give you data in chunks of smaller size (say 500) and with every successful request you can append data to your dropdown menu. This way, the rendering is not blocked until all options are populated.

Comment: Yeah that is much true. but I want the logic for this one. @arjunlal

Comment: I've updated the answer with how you can optimize in this case. @user6433464